# Is there any way that can make each pod gets its own volume in RC template?

Tags: kubernetes

When setting a `persistentVolumeClaim` in the kubernetes `ReplicationController` template, each pod will share the same persistent volume.

Is there any way that can make each pod gets its own volume in RC template?
i don't want to create many RCs with `replicas=1` with distinct `persistentVolumeClaims`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You might get better responses if you can show that you have attempted something.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. A replication controller is a pod definition (mostly). And a pod is a collection of containers and attached volumes (mostly). Each pod is identical with the other pods.

So, again, no, you can't have different definitions for each replica, they are all identical.

Comment: This is correct for now.  We know it is a pain point, but we don't have an implementation yet.